# SwiftUI: state from NavigationLink losing state?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following code:

```
enum SelectionItem:Int {
    case first
    case second
}


class ContentViewModel:ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var selectedItem:SelectionItem?
    
}

struct MyCar {
    let name:String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @StateObject var model = ContentViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(car: MyCar(name: "FIRST")) ,
                                   tag: .first,
                                   selection: $model.selectedItem) {
                        Text("FIRST")
                    }
                }
                Section {
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(car: MyCar(name: "SECOND")) ,
                                   tag: .second,
                                   selection: $model.selectedItem) {
                        Text("SECOND")
                    }
                }
                
                Section {
                    switch model.selectedItem {
                    case .first:
                        Text("CURRENT SELECTION FIRST")
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                    case .second:
                        Text("CURRENT SELECTION SECOND")
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                    default:
                        Text("NO SELECTION")
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
            Text("Select an item")
        }
        .onChange(of: model.selectedItem) { newValue in
            print("new selection: \(newValue)")
        }
    }
}


struct DetailsView: View {
    
    let car:MyCar
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(car.name)
            
            NavigationLink {
                DetailsView(car: car)
            } label: {
                Text("GO")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The behavior is this:

[image]

Can someone explain to me why the selection state is lost and the highlight on the "FIRST" or "SECOND" item on the left is lost too when I go one level deep from details? Clicking on "GO" will cause `selectedItem` to be set to `nil` and the cell selection to disappear losing visual state. Why is that? How can I prevent `selectedItem` to not go to nil and the visual selection on FIRST and SECOND to stay?

Comment: Because  NavigationView does not store path, the selection state is per-level, you go to next level and it overrides previous one. That's why Apple deprecated NavigationView, finally, and introduced NavigationStack, which keeps persistently of selection history throughout entire path.

Comment: I see. How would I go about overcoming this problem pre iOS16?

Comment: You will need to implement a View Router in SwiftUI. There are lots of examples on line, though they can be a bit fragile.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one detail link in a navigation view, if you want more you have to set detail false, e.g.

```
struct DetailsView: View {
    
    let car:MyCar
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(car.name)
            
            NavigationLink {
                DetailsView(car: car)
            } label: {
                Text("GO")
            }
            .isDetailLink(false)
        }
    }
}
```

I would also recommend removing the view model object and using `@State` instead, SwiftUI is designed to use structs and you'll get less bugs that way.

Comment: when I add `.isDetailLink(false)` like shown the selected cell still goes away. does not keep selected UI state...